# .next_sibling returning type NoneType

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am pretty new to Python and am trying to access information of a  tag's next sibling. The HTML code looks something like this:

```
<h4>
    <i>
        <b>"Title"</b>
    </i>
</h4>
<i>"Description"</i>
```

I am running a *for* loop that runs through every *h4* tag and finds all siblings until a new *h4* tag is reached. In between these two *h4* tags there can be multiple siblings. When I run my code:

```
title = course.find_all('h4')[x]
array = []
sibling = title
while True:
    sibling = sibling.next_sibling
    try:
        siblingType = sibling.name
    except AttributeError:
        siblingType = ''
    if siblingType != 'h4':
        array.append(sibling.text)
    else:
        break
```

The program returns that the *siblingType* variable is of *'NoneType'* and the sibling is empty where it obviously should be of type *i*.

What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: With BeautifulSoup, the next sibling of “h4” in your example is the newline character between “h4” and “i”.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the newline between “h4” and “I”. Such a node has the type `NavigableString`.

Another way is to search the next non-empty node of type `Tag` and then break the loop if another “h4” is met:

```
array = []
sibling = title.next_sibling

while True:
    while sibling and not isinstance(sibling, bs4.element.Tag):
        sibling = sibling.next_sibling
    if sibling is None or sibling.name == "h4":
        break
    array.append(sibling.get_text())
    sibling = sibling.next_sibling

print(array)
```

You get:

```
['"Description"']
```

This solution also works for something like this:

```
<h4>
<i>
<b>"Title"</b>
</i>
</h4>
<i>"Description"</i>
<i>"Description2"</i>
<h4>
<i>
<b>"Title2"</b>
</i>
</h4>
```

You get:

```
['"Description"', '"Description2"']
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is a better way of writing the while loop but for some weird reason my sibling is not of type *'NavigableString'* but of *'NoneType'*. Because of that, the while loop breaks and returns an empty array. Any thoughts?

Comment: No, I can’t reproduce that. Do you have a complete example?